# (unknown_cost_value) in costmap2D

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i am trying to set the parameters for costmap but i dont know why  this paramter is set to -1 neither what options do i have if i need to change it

Also could someone  explain to me what this parameter exactly does cause i am not sure ??

Thank you in advance ! <3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408712/(unknown_cost_value)--in-costmap2d/) by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2022-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its the cost value if you don't know what's in a given occupancy cell. If you have a static map, that could be unexplored regions. If its in a local costmap without a static map, it would be area that haven't been covered by any sensor data yet so you don't know anything about it yet. So this is the cost of unknown space. The value of 255 (or -1) is special so that algorithms know that's unknown space and can act accordingly. But you can override this so that unknown space is always treated as free (if set to 0) or occupied (if set to 254) or anything in-between to your heart's desire.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0